# When I was in the house by the forge, I saw a key that disappeard when I clicked on it

Tags: candy-box-2

I have looked all over for that key but cannot find it. Do you have any idea where it is at?

Comment: Check your inventory, you might just collected it.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't a key, it was a lollipop.

There are no keys in the game found in houses but there is a house containing several lollipops. I'm assuming that's what you found.

The lollipop disappeared because you took it- it should be displayed underneath your number of candies. Lollipops are a currency, similar to candies. You'll find more uses for them later in the game.

Comment: I've always wanted to answer a question with "it wasn't a key, it was a lollipop".